# PHP isset() bug? in combination with NULL

Tags: php, debugging

Good day,

I've got a strange error.

Generally speaking, or at least to my knowledge.
In PHP when using `isset()`, it plainly checks if the variable exists. It does not check what's in it or if it is empty.

If I want to know if it is an empty variable. Then I should be using `empty()`.

Now I am using the following code

```
    if(isset($tab['content']) === true){
```

However, I found out that my code always took the *else* statement.

```
    ///######## IF NO CONTENT SET
    else {
        debug((int)isset($tab['content']), $tab, gettype($tab['content']));
```

So I parsed {hence the debug function} the variable contents and found out that 'content' has actually been set. But it is NULL.

```
0




----


Array
(
    [title] => Location
    [id] => location
    [url] => 
    [content] => 
    [active] => 
    [ajax] => 
    [icon] => 
)



----



NULL
```

This is pretty strange to my opinion.

```
Since : (int)isset($tab['content'])
Returns : 0
```

And

```
gettype($tab['content'])
Returns : NULL
```

Am I missing something?
What am I doing wrong? Or am I running into one of the notorious PHP features?

### **Edit**

As pointed out by : **Karsten Koop**
I overlooked the fact that I should not use `isset()`. But rather: `array_key_exists()`

So this is my mistake. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `isset()` does indeed check the contents of your variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php -- And have a look at https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/ -- see if it helps.

Comment: It goes to else because the variable is `NULL` so it can't be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

BTW, `isset()` returns a boolean, there is no need to use `===true` in your `if`.